# SQL server 2012 SP_HELPTEXT extra lines issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, ide, formatting

I am using SQL server 2012, & always use `SP_HELPTEXT` to get my previously created Stored Procedures, In previous versions of SQL server there were no issues in this process but in 2012, My Stored Procedures come with extra lines, for example this is the procedure that I wrote

```
Create proc SP_Test
as
begin
 Select * 
 from table_ABC
end
```

Now after using `SP_HELPTEXT` with this procedure (or any other procedure), I am getting this output

```
Create proc SP_Test

as

begin

 Select * 

 from table_ABC

end
```

Do any one else also facing this problem or I am the only one on this planet to struggle with this issue ??
Does any body know how to solve this issue ??

Configuration of my SQL server is as follows (copied from **Help -> About** )

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio          11.0.2100.60
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools        11.0.2100.60
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)         6.1.7601.17514
Microsoft MSXML                     3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer             9.0.8112.16421
Microsoft .NET Framework                4.0.30319.269
Operating System                    6.1.7601
```

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Don't see that behavior here (SQL Server Express 2012).

Comment: I have mentioned my Version's configuration now, plz have a look at it too

Comment: You probably know this, but you can right click a stored procedure and `Modify` will give you the source.  RedGate's free [SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) helps you quickly select a stored procedure.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I can replicate this behaviour if I run `sp_helptext` with `Results to grid` set, then copy and paste the results from grid into a new query or any other text editor.

This seems to be a change in the behaviour of `sp_helptext` from previous editions, since this effect isn't displayed with standard grid result sets.

The simplest work-around will be to run `sp_helptext` with `Results to text` set (`Query` -> `Results to` > `Results to text`, shortcut `CTRL` + `T`.

You may need to increase the maximum number of characters per line in `Results to text` to get the output you expect - `Tools` > `Options` > `Query Results` > `Results to text` - set "maximum number of characters displayed in each column" to the maximum value of 8192.

Answer (score 6):

A better workaround (compared to use Results to text) in my opinion is to create an sp_helptext2 storedproc as explained here:

http://sql-javier-villegas.blogspot.com/2012/08/a-workaround-for-sphelptext-bug-in-ssms.html

Note: that solution has a bug leaving out the last line if there is no new line at the end. 
Corrected T-SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_helptext2] (@ProcName NVARCHAR(256))
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @PROC_TABLE TABLE (X1  NVARCHAR(MAX))

  DECLARE @Proc NVARCHAR(MAX)
  DECLARE @Procedure NVARCHAR(MAX)
  DECLARE @ProcLines TABLE (PLID INT IDENTITY(1,1), Line NVARCHAR(MAX))

  SELECT @Procedure = 'SELECT DEFINITION FROM '+db_name()+'.SYS.SQL_MODULES WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('''+@ProcName+''')'

  insert into @PROC_TABLE (X1)
        exec  (@Procedure)

  SELECT @Proc=X1 from @PROC_TABLE

  WHILE CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@Proc) > 0
  BEGIN
        INSERT @ProcLines
        SELECT LEFT(@Proc,CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@Proc)-1)
        SELECT @Proc = SUBSTRING(@Proc,CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@Proc)+2,LEN(@Proc))
  END
  --* inserts last line
  insert @ProcLines 
  select @Proc ;

  SELECT Line FROM @ProcLines ORDER BY PLID
END
```

Comment: @Dram: sorry - it worked for me for years. I just recently stopped using because it is not necessary if you have SSMS 2014.

Answer (score 5):

The answer posted by Rufo still produces blank lines. A little change in the last line of code solved the issue for me. Here is the edited code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_helptext2] (@ProcName NVARCHAR(256))
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @PROC_TABLE TABLE (X1  NVARCHAR(MAX))

  DECLARE @Proc NVARCHAR(MAX)
  DECLARE @Procedure NVARCHAR(MAX)
  DECLARE @ProcLines TABLE (PLID INT IDENTITY(1,1), Line NVARCHAR(MAX))

  SELECT @Procedure = 'SELECT DEFINITION FROM '+db_name()+'.SYS.SQL_MODULES WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('''+@ProcName+''')'

  insert into @PROC_TABLE (X1)
        exec  (@Procedure)

  SELECT @Proc=X1 from @PROC_TABLE

  WHILE CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@Proc) > 0
  BEGIN
        INSERT @ProcLines
        SELECT LEFT(@Proc,CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@Proc)-1)
        SELECT @Proc = SUBSTRING(@Proc,CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@Proc)+2,LEN(@Proc))
  END
 --* inserts last line
 insert @ProcLines 
 select @Proc ;

 --edited here. (where Line<>'')
 SELECT Line FROM @ProcLines where Line<>'' ORDER BY PLID
END
```

Even though this removes the "original carriage returns", but this is way better to live with. I migrated by DB from SQL 2008 to SQL 2012 and all the stored procedures (more than 200) were returned with around 5 carriage returns after every line of code when using sp_helptext.

The above code helped me resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below query to get exact SP query without extra spaces:

```
(SELECT  OBJECT_DEFINITION (OBJECT_ID('SPname' )))
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote another workaround that just replaces the CrLf:

```
DECLARE @results table ([Text] nvarchar(255))

INSERT @results
Exec sp_helptext spStudyRoleCacheFlushNotificationGet

SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE([Text], CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), '')
FROM @results
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Rufo's solution, but I just realized it breaks when the database has a dash. Example: `[ST-SALES]`.

For what it's worth, this is an updated answer based on Rufo's solution.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_helptext2] (@ProcName NVARCHAR(256))
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @PROC_TABLE TABLE (X1  NVARCHAR(MAX))

  DECLARE @Proc NVARCHAR(MAX)
  DECLARE @Procedure NVARCHAR(MAX)
  DECLARE @ProcLines TABLE (PLID INT IDENTITY(1,1), Line NVARCHAR(MAX))

  SELECT @Procedure = 'SELECT DEFINITION FROM ['+db_name()+'].SYS.SQL_MODULES WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('''+@ProcName+''')'

  insert into @PROC_TABLE (X1)
        exec  (@Procedure)

  SELECT @Proc=X1 from @PROC_TABLE

  WHILE CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@Proc) > 0
  BEGIN
        INSERT @ProcLines
        SELECT LEFT(@Proc,CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@Proc)-1)
        SELECT @Proc = SUBSTRING(@Proc,CHARINDEX(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),@Proc)+2,LEN(@Proc))
  END
  --* inserts last line
  insert @ProcLines 
  select @Proc ;

  SELECT Line FROM @ProcLines ORDER BY PLID
END
```

Answer (score -1):

I too faced this issue for a view.

Below are steps i used to resolve the issue (note only a temporary fix)

1)select the query

2)then right click and open in query designer

3)click ok

you would notice all the extra spaces are removed.

Note: this works only for simple queries not for procedures,etc

Answer (score -1):

There are two type of solution which you can use for remove extra space from sp_helptext output

1. Goto Tools>Option>Query Results>Result to text (From drop down list)
2. Copy sp_helptext output
   Paste in Notepad++. open find and replace window by pressing cntl+H enter the following text to replace with new text as in given picture.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWJ31.jpg)

Comment: That sounds more like a method to post-process the output, rather than actually changing the output format.