# sp_helptext changes my indentation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, indentation

I'm using SQL server 2008, whenever I indent my code inside SP it moves 4 spaces.
But then when I open the code again using sp_helptext command, then the code is indented only 1 space. Is there a way to fix this?
Note: I can't right click into SP to modify it, the only way I can look into SP is using the sp_helptext

Comment: Is it actually 4 spaces, or is it really a single tab character?

Comment: a single tab is 4 spaces. basically I find that using sp_helptext changes my formatting, and due to restrictions on the computer Im working on right clicking the SP is not available.

Comment: No, a single tab is ASCII character number 9, which SSMS happens to represent by 4 space characters (ASCII 32), at least in the code editor. This is a setting that can be changed. It's possible (a guess) that the single tab in your output, being in the output window, is being shown as a single space instead.

Comment: Stop using `sp_helptext`. Try `SELECT definition FROM sys.sql_modules WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.procedure_name');`

Comment: @AaronBertrand That is an interesting query but it's making it worse. With this query I get the whole SP in one cell, copying it into the window totally messes everything up

Comment: Stop using results to grid.

Comment: please find solutions here [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061642/sql-server-2012-sp-helptext-extra-lines-issue)

Answer (score 5):

found solution in a different forum.
When executing sp_helptext spName, just set Results to Text instead of Results to Grid and that will maintain formating