# Why does sp_helptext in SQL Server return different results?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am building a query that searches through my results of `sp_helptext` but sometimes `sp_helptext` outputs this:

[image]

instead of this:

[image]

Is there anyway to get my preferred return format of `sp_helptext` each time?

And what is causing image 1 to happen?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please always provide source code, error messages and other textual information as inline plain text rather than external pictures. Text is searchable, reusable and normally easier to read. Also, don't forget to use tags to identify the technology (this site covers all programming languages).

Comment: you meant to say formatting?

Comment: I agree the question is not entirely clear. Do you have Unix-style line feeds? If so, are you asking how to configure Management Studio, how to postprocess the output or how to alter `sp_helptext` itself?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061642/sql-server-2012-sp-helptext-extra-lines-issue               chek here

Comment: I don't thinks its unclear at all. In SSMS the system proc "sp_helptext" gives me different type of results on different procs. I would like to know why?

Comment: @Jacquespax did you find the answer for the "Why"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sp_helptext` has some intentional quirks built-in, and some "unexpected" behaviors.

I put that in quotes because most people who use it haven't actually read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176112.aspx), let alone gone into the system procedures and looked at the actual definition of the procedure itself.

I tend to use the definitions stored in the system tables instead:

```
SELECT definition
FROM sys.all_sql_modules S 
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(S.object_id) = 'MySProc'
;
```

This typically gives me more consistent results in some regards, and also allows me to do immediate alterations if need be.  Using sp_helptext a lot of people store the output in a variable and then modify the variable value; with a `SELECT` straight from `sys.all_sql_modules`, you can just perform desired modifications directly on the returned value without any variable operations.

(By the way, this same query here works on `sp_helptext` itself, and you're welcome to look at its definition to try to understand what it's doing and what's happening to your definitions.  Just make sure you don't accidentally `ALTER` it...)

I know this doesn't exactly answer your question of "Why is this happening?", and I hope that someone else's response will help you with that.  In the meantime, you can try taking a look at the system tables and see if maybe they will provide you with a working solution.

Good luck!

**First Edit:**
If you're looking to find dependencies, depending on your version of SQL you can use this:

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(D.referenced_server_name,@@SERVERNAME) + '.' + ISNULL(D.referenced_database_name,DB_NAME()) + '.' + D.Referenced_Entity_Name AS [Referenced Tables]
FROM sys.procedures P
INNER JOIN sys.sql_expression_dependencies D
    ON P.object_id = D.referencing_id
WHERE P.name = 'MySProc'
;
```

Returns a concatenated string:

```
[Referenced Tables]
--------------------
ServerName\InstanceName.DBName.TableName
```

Comment: Thanks ! you see i am trying to see what procs on DB1 are dependant of tables on DB2. Using sp_helptext works (when i use substring) but only if the results is like image 2. I need a whole list of the actual table names that is being queried in DB2

Comment: So you're actually looking for dependencies between databases? I.E. SProc1 in DB1 queries tables in DB2?

Comment: Yes, the actual table names for each proc. My query works... only if sp_helptext plays nicely haha.( Like image 2)

Comment: Gotcha.  Now that you've given me that information, I've updated my answer with some more relevant information (I think).  I don't know what procedure you're running, obviously, but this simple query will show you all things referenced by a given SProc.  Maybe it will help, anyway...

Comment: Thats a awesome query. But it gives me null if it has to look "across" DBs.

Comment: @Jacquespax Wow, sorry - stupid mistake on my part.  Easily fixed, though.  Updated the query - can you try again and let me know if it at least returns the string you wanted? It works on my servers... Just want to know if it's incomplete.  Thanks! :)